# CSS Fixed/Absolute positioned <div>

Tags: css, compass-sass

How do I put a div `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` until the scroll reaches the footer, then it's `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` of the content div.

I want the div to always stick to the bottom of the viewport, then stick to the bottom of the content div and not cover up my footer.

Bonus points for compass/sass solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQjSS/) (I used yours as a base, forked it though) you can see a working example of what you want, with a supposed footer height of 100px.

Here's the JS needed:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 100) {
        $('div#scrolled').css({'bottom' : '100px'});
    } else {
        $('div#scrolled').css({'bottom' : '0px'});
    }
});
```

It checks, on scroll, if the scroll reached the bottom plus 100 pixels, and if so, it sets the bottom of the fixed element to 100px. The bad point is that it's not progressive, and the fixed element jumps when the footer appears. You cant just remove the 100 in the if statement if you want the footer to pop when the user reaches the absolute bottom: `if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { ...`

UPDATE:

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pQjSS/1/) is the "progressive" version of the above code.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 100) {
        var bottom = 100 - ($(document).height() - ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) + "px";
        $('div#scrolled').css({'bottom' : bottom});
    } else {
        $('div#scrolled').css({'bottom' : '0px'});
    }
});
```

Now, instead of changing the bottom to 100px whenever the user scroll is under 101px from the bottom, it calculates the position the fixed element should have depending on the scroll

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed! On the website I'm adding this to it does show some performance slowdown but that is probably caused by the rest of the bulk of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Stick to `position:fixed`, and add `margin-bottom:100px` (when your `div` has a height of 100px) to your footer, so that that div doesn't cover up your footer.

An alternative (not recommended), would involve JavaScript, detecting whether `scrollHeight == scrollTop + offsetHeight`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The only thing that margin-bottom has is that it is left floating in the middle of the page instead of fixed to the bottom of the viewport before you get to the footer in your scroll. Is there a way to dynamically change that from margin-bottom: 0 to 100px;?

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cDeed/) illustrating your current issue?

Comment: Question is, can the yellow div stick to the bottom of the viewport but not go past the red footer div? http://jsfiddle.net/cDeed/1/

Comment: @sway Extend the `margin-bottom` to the height of that specific element: http://jsfiddle.net/cDeed/2/. If the height is not fixed, you have to use JavaScript, and obtain the real height of the fixed element using `element.offsetHeight`.